# Measure the download speed of a specific public server of your own choice, not the speed of your ISP

Tags: browser, internet-connection, browser-addons, speed, measurement

How can a common computer user ("[Your Momma](https://foxtrot.fandom.com/wiki/Your_Momma_Thinks_Square_Roots_Are_Vegetables)") measure the average download speed **of any (random) specific public server** of your own choice (e.g. "https://superuser.com" :) ), preferably using already installed tools (such as the browser or its plugins) or an online tool?

I am not successful in finding anything on the internet, all the searches such as "how to measure specific server download speed" always bring only a speed test of my ISP, or a speed test to a specific server selectable only from the tool's own list, or a specialized programming tools.

What I need to measure is rather an "effective speed", so it would be enough to have a browser plugin which sums up the total time of all the resources read from a server and divides it by their total size. I am aware that this is not exactly the server bandwidth, but effectively it can tell the user if the bottleneck is their own connection or the internet resource.

Comment: You can only measure some else’s bandwidth (or what you get of their total, anyway) if your own bandwidth is significantly higher.

Comment: @DanielB This is obvious. I want to determine when the limiting factor is my own connection and when it is the network resource, and if increasing my internet connection would help or not. Hence I am *also* looking for some online tool, which might have better connectivity then my own connection.

Comment: The only possibilities are if the server you are wishing to test has a specific speed test feature, or if they host files of sufficient size to establish a reliable speed.  You cannot just make a server give you a speed test mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only measure the real bandwidth of a server by a program that
is running *on that server*.

Your internet connection to the server passes through several intermediaries,
where each may have its own constraints. Not to mention the software
running on the server, which may cap connections, and so on for every
server and router through which passes the connection.

You can only measure the *effective bandwidth* of your connection to the
server, by observing the speed by which you may download files.
This speed will also fluctuate continuously, as conditions change on
the server and all intermediate servers through which passes your
connection.

I have observed that the usual case is that download speed increases up
to a certain constant level, which may perhaps be the maximum
effective bandwidth. Over time it may even start to decrease
as conditions become less favorable, then sometimes return to its
previous level (or not).

Comment: See my edit. Yes, effective bandwidth is good enough. But is there any tool supporting it easily enough?

Comment: A download manager will usually give good information. In a pinch, even Task Manager gives good graphical representation in its network tab.

Answer (score 1):

Servers offered by regular "Speed test" tools have one thing in common: they all publish HTTP URLs which consistently serve a *large* amount of data to the client – large enough that a measurement could be done over at least several seconds (giving time for TCP flow control to settle, etc).

The same does not apply to "any random public server" (e.g. https://superuser.com), as most URLs hosting ordinary HTML webpages are tiny in comparison to the server's upload speed – with superuser.com serving "only" 200 kB, you'd end up measuring the webapp's processing time and network latency more than you'd measure the actual throughput.

(And although it'd still be technically easy for a "speed test" service to set up its servers to offer a mode where it downloads an external URL into the test server, I kind of suspect that this would expose it to a few *legal* risks.)

So if you want reliable results, you can only measure servers that you're in control of (so that the you could make the server publish a 1GB file via HTTP at a known URL that the test service could download). This is already beyond "a common computer user" or "browser plugin" capabilities.

Because of that, I suggest that the easiest way to measure your own server is to 1) rent *another* virtual server close to the first one, 2) SSH to the temporary server and `wget -O /dev/null` the large URL that you prepared (or even run `iperf3` on both servers now that you can), 3) discard the temporary server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot accept **two** answers :)